# What is the complexity of Model.columns or Model.column_names on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

What is the complexity of active record `Model.columns` or `Model.column_names` operation on rails?

Basically I have an option of either hard coding it like that:

```
do_something(:column_name1)
do_something(:column_name2)
do_something(:column_name3)
```

or I can do that as following:

```
columns = Model.columns
columns.each do |c|
   do_something(c.name)
end
```

I want to use the second one, because I have to do that in couple of models and if I choose the second option it saves me time and lines of code. But I am thinking if I had to face any time penalty at run time or not?

Comment: `column_names` is just `columns.map(&:name)` (with some caching in an instance variable). The data behind `columns` should only be loaded from the database once.  Are you sure you need to `do_something` to every column? Even `id`, `updated_at`, and `created_at`?

Comment: In a web application, where so much time spent is not CPU time, you should probably not worry about a single method call. Especially not before you implement it.

When or just before your application goes live, you can (and should) profile it, and then you can focus on fixing the real bottle necks.

Comment: @muistooshort, in my real code I am removing id and _at columns. Since it is loaded from database once, I think I am safe to use it. Thank you.

Comment: @Drenmi thank you, your comment helped.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need of **hard-coding** in both scenarios.

If you need more information about a field, you should use `Model.columns`

You should go with `Model.column_names` I feel.

Then you could just call `Model.column_names.each {|attr| do_something(attr)}`